# The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available / Resolving raspberrypi-kernel failed: Name or service not known

Tags: raspbian, kernel, debian, repository

I would like to virtualize debian bullseye for raspberry on top of my jetson nano using qemu and kvm because it is necessary to install this repo :

https://www.hackster.io/stanton/smart-snoring-correction-028e79

Below you can see what happens when I run the setup script on two different situations. On the first one I've used the repositories of the raspberry debian bullseye :

```
root@buster:/home/marietto/Desktop# ./ss-setup.sh

+ set -e
+ branch=master
+ sudo apt -y update
Get:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye InRelease [23.3 kB]
Get:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye InRelease [15.0 kB]    
Get:3 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease [11.0 kB]          
Err:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 82B129927FA3303E
Get:4 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye/main armhf Packages [13.2 MB]
Get:5 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye/contrib armhf Packages [60.2 kB]
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
W: GPG error: http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 82B129927FA3303E
E: The repository 'http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

On the second one I've used the repositories of the debian bullseye :

```
root@buster:/home/marietto/Desktop# ./ss-setup.sh
+ set -e
+ branch=master
+ tmp_folder=/tmp/dumping_ground
+ mkdir /tmp/dumping_ground
+ pushd /tmp/dumping_ground
/tmp/dumping_ground /home/marietto/Desktop
+ git clone https://github.com/respeaker/seeed-voicecard.git
Cloning into 'seeed-voicecard'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 982, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (32/32), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (22/22), done.
remote: Total 982 (delta 15), reused 23 (delta 10), pack-reused 950
Receiving objects: 100% (982/982), 1.39 MiB | 941.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (619/619), done.
+ pushd seeed-voicecard
/tmp/dumping_ground/seeed-voicecard /tmp/dumping_ground /home/marietto/Desktop
+ sed -i 's/^FORCE/##FORCE/g' install.sh
+ sed -i s/#FORCE/FORCE/g install.sh
+ sudo ./install.sh --compat-kernel

### will compile with a compatible kernel...

### Install required tool packages
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease                                    
Hit:3 http://ftp.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports InRelease                                  
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease                          
Hit:5 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                    
Reading package lists... Done                        
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libasound2-plugins is already the newest version (1.2.2-2).
dkms is already the newest version (2.8.4-3).
git is already the newest version (1:2.30.2-1).
i2c-tools is already the newest version (4.2-1+b1).

### Uninstall previous dkms module

### Install required kernel package
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
W: --force-yes is deprecated, use one of the options starting with --allow instead.
E: Unable to locate package raspberrypi-kernel-headers
E: Unable to locate package raspberrypi-kernel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-raspi
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-raspi
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-raspi
E: Unable to locate package raspberrypi-kernel
dpkg-query: no packages found matching raspberrypi-kernel
--2021-04-21 21:42:00--  http://raspberrypi-kernel__armhf.deb/
Resolving raspberrypi-kernel__armhf.deb (raspberrypi-kernel__armhf.deb)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address 'raspberrypi-kernel__armhf.deb'
--2021-04-21 21:42:00--  http://raspberrypi-kernel__armhf.deb/
Resolving raspberrypi-kernel__armhf.deb (raspberrypi-kernel__armhf.deb)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address 'raspberrypi-kernel__armhf.deb'
--2021-04-21 21:42:00--  http://raspberrypi-kernel__armhf.deb/
Resolving raspberrypi-kernel__armhf.deb (raspberrypi-kernel__armhf.deb)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address 'raspberrypi-kernel__armhf.deb'
dpkg-deb: error: '/tmp/raspberrypi-kernel__armhf.deb' is not a Debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/raspberrypi-kernel__armhf.deb (--install):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/raspberrypi-kernel__armhf.deb
Error: Install kernel or header failed
```

On both situations I'm not able to reach the end of the script. On the first one because the debian bullseye for raspberry repositories aren't accepted. On the second one because they are needed. So,what can I do ? Which scenario is the correct one ?

Answer (score 3):

To solve the GPG error:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 82B129927FA3303E
sudo apt update
```

Comment: ubuntu keys are valid also for debian raspberry ?

Comment: @Marietto No it is the raspbian key.